# CSS class not apply in HTML File

Tags: css

hi i linked the css file but it didnt apply in the website please help me out

```
>     <html>
>     <head>
>         <title>itay's website</title>
>         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <div class="main">
>     
>         </div>
> 
>     
>     </body>
>     
>     
>     
>     </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure main div has height and width, otherwise you won´t notice changes...

Comment: .main{ 
    width: 100;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: linear-gradient(to right, #9c27b9, #8ecdff)

}

Comment: is this what you ment?

Comment: Here you go, you missed units for width ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have given the right path for the CSS file or not. Or else put some content and apply css styles on them and see the changes.